# problem about createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I come from China.When I do my homework,I find some problem,but I cann't solve it.
This is my code.
console information:2021-05-28 16:41:32.525 5706-5746/com.example.chat W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

```
private fun registerUser(Email:String,Password:String,userName:String)
{
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this)
        {
            if(it.isSuccessful)
            {
                val user:FirebaseUser?=auth.currentUser
                val userId:String=user!!.uid

                databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId)
                val hashmap:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap()
                hashmap?.put("userId",userId)
                hashmap?.put("userName",userName)
                hashmap?.put("profileImage","")

                databaseReference.setValue(hashmap).addOnCompleteListener(this)
                {
                    if(it.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        val intent= Intent(this@SignupActivity,HomeActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Waiting for your help.thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post more logs?

Comment: You haven't handled any of the cases where `it.isSuccessful` is `false`. You need to log/handle `it.getException` as appropriate

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.chat.SignupActivity.registerUser(SignupActivity.kt:71)
        at com.example.chat.SignupActivity.access$registerUser(SignupActivity.kt:15)
        at com.example.chat.SignupActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(SignupActivity.kt:58)

Comment: I think there is an error in createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.So I cann't create new user

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make sure that you have enabled "Email and Password" Login in your Firebase console**

**2. Try your app on a real android device, not just the emulator. Sometimes that does the trick**

**3. Make sure you have an internet connection.**

**4. Make sure you have the permission to acces the internet**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

(5. Firebase Auth doesn't accept passwords that are too unsecure. Try an 8 character long password)

Your code seems to be correct.